# Unable to set up the dotnet client for a signalR chat application

Tags: c#, .net, signalr

I am trying to create a chat application using signalR. Instead of using the javascript client I want to use the dotnet client.
This is my class (refer docs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/dotnet-client?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio)

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using EO.WebBrowser;
using EO.WebBrowser.DOM;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ChatApp.Hubs
{
    public class MainWindow : Window
    {
        HubConnection connection;
        private string URL = "https://localhost:7131/chatHub";
        public MainWindow() 
        {
            connection = new HubConnectionBuilder().WithUrl(this.URL).Build();

            connection.Closed += async (error) => 
            {
                await Task.Delay(new Random().Next(0,5) * 1000);
                await connection.StartAsync();
            };
        }

        public async void EstablistConnection()
        {
            try
            {
                await connection.StartAsync();
                App.Debugger("test", "TEST", "Client", "Connection", $"Connection started at {DateTime.Now}");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                App.Debugger("exception", "ERROR", "Client", "Connection", ex.Message);
            }
        }
        public async void OnMessage() 
        {
            connection.On<string, string>("ReceiveMessage", (user, message) =>
            {
                App.Debugger("test", "TEST", "Client", "Connection", $"{user} sends {message} at {DateTime.Now}");
            });
        }

        public async void Send(string user, string message) 
        {
            try 
            {
                await connection.InvokeAsync("SendMessage",user,"Hello, world");
                Console.WriteLine("Message sent!!");
            }
            catch (Exception ex) 
            {
                App.Debugger("exception", "ERROR", "Client", "Send", ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

On running the application I checked the browser's console and I got the following message:

> Information: Normalizing '/chatHub' to
> 'https://localhost:7137/chatHub'. Information: WebSocket connected to
> wss://localhost:7137/chatHub?id=WQQv8OC0imuPlGfoZwwJKQ.

But I got an exception that said

> "No connection could be made because the target machine actively
> refused it. (localhost:7131)"

Comment: Could it be the different port? `7137` vs `7131`?

Comment: If not the port, add a logger to the client

Comment: Is your signalr server running?